# Operator in class initialization?

Tags: python, blender

I've coded in Python about year and more, but today for the first time I saw something like this:

```
class ObjectSelector(bpy.types.Operator):
     bl_idname = "lod.search"
     bl_label = "Search lod"
     bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

     searchKey: bpy.props.StringProperty(
          name="Search",
     )
```

This is code from Blender python plugin, and I want to ask what is `searchKey` in this case, because `bl_idname` is variable of class, but what in the world is `searchKey` and how even is this thing is called? Is it something like javascript class creation: `const tmp = {searchKey: ""}`?

Comment: That's an attribute name with a type annotation.

Comment: `searchKey` is a field, uninitialized, that has type `bpy.props.StringProperty(name='Search')`. Presumably its picked up by the metaclass that `bpy.types.Operator` comes with.

Comment: Welcome to python. You're only scratching the surface until you encounter metaclasses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for answer, so to end this discussion, its basicly almost same thing like annotations in Java, which serve to another class / or class itself to construct data based on this anotation.

Comment: Also see [PEP 484 -- Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/).